# Custom Annotation in asp.net not working?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, annotations, data-annotations

```
public class CheckCreditNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public CheckCreditNumberAttribute()
    : base("Not a valid Account Number.")
      {}
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
     if(value!=null)
        {
            string input = value.ToString();
            int i;
            int sum = 0;
            int count = 1;
            for(i=input.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                if(count%2!=0)
                {
                    sum += i;
                }
                else
                {
                    int newNum = i * 2;
                    if(newNum>9)
                    {
                        newNum -= 9;
                    }
                    sum += newNum;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if(sum%10==0)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;

            }
            else
            {
                var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
            }

        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
} }
```

Above is a Custom annotation class.

This is in a model class.This Annotation is not working on run time.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Account Number is Required")]
[CheckCreditNumber(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Account Number.")]
[Display(Name = "Bank Account Number")]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{14,16}",ErrorMessage ="Account number should be of 14-16 digits.")]
public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
```

Here CheckCreditNumber is a class inheriting validate Attribute class.
Please suggest the proper solution !Thanks

Comment: Does your CheckCreditNumberAttribute.IsValid function gets hit when you post?

Comment: No,that is my problem. It is not getting hit.

Comment: Pls post your controller action method.

Comment: public ActionResult DonateGroup(FormCollection obj)
        {
            ASYRepository dalObj = new ASYRepository();
            string bankAccountNumber =Convert.ToString(obj["BankAccountNumber"]);

        }

Comment: Try using Model class name instead of FormCollection in DonateGroup. Should work.

Comment: But other annotations like Required ,Range are working well.

Comment: Ya, but doesn't work for custom annotations.

Comment: It's still not working after using Model class name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, keep using Model class name in action method DonateGroup().

Then try creating Adapter class for your attribute like this:

```
public class CheckCreditNumberAttributeAdapter : System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator<CheckCreditNumberAttribute>
{
    public CheckCreditNumberAttributeAdapter(System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context,CheckCreditNumberAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {


    }

    public static void SelfRegister()
    {
        System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
            .RegisterAdapter(
                typeof(CheckCreditNumberAttribute),
                typeof(CheckCreditNumberAttributeAdapter));
    }        
}
```

And then register in Global.asax.cs Application_Start function

```
CheckCreditNumberAttributeAdapter.SelfRegister();
```

Hope it works.